# Can i use another H-bridge for this bipolar stepper motor drive?

Tags: stepper-motor, microchip, h-bridge

I am driving a bipolar stepper motor with a H- bridge. For this sheet:

[image]
[source](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/stepper-motor-sn754410)

Can i use my L293DNE H-bridge driver instead of the pictured SN754410NE? Will there be any consequences for this?

I have earlier used the L293D chip for this design:

[image]

Needing only 2 controlling pins from the microcontroller it seemed much better, but i have never gotten it to be as smooth in controlling as the top driver sheet, there seems to be software issues when using the arduino library to control it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L293D has an output current capacity of 600mA compared to L293 and SN754410 that can provide up to 1A in the outputs but apart from that the drivers have the same functionality and one can replace the other.

If you read the headlines of the SN754410 characteristics in the datasheet this is already noted

> Functional Replacements for SGS L293 and SGS L293D